# Qt - How to convert from QObject to UI elements?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qwidget

I am working in Qt 4.7, and I have a QWidget object in my dialog. I need to go through each of the children and extract the current text into a QStringList. Every other object is a QCheckBox, and the rest are QComboBoxes (I would just need the text portion of both). So far the only way I could think of to do this would be to use the children() function to get them as QObject*'s and cast them, like this:

```
QStringList textlist;
for(int i = 0; i < ui->myWidget->children().size(); i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        QCheckBox *q = (QCheckBox *)ui->myWidget->children().at(i);
        textlist.append(q->text());
    }
    else
    {
        QComboBox *q = (QComboBox *)ui->myWidget->children().at(i);
        textlist.append(q->currentText());
    }
}
```

However, when I try to use this, it builds and compiles fine, but then crashes when it's run. I checked and both classes are subclasses (albeit indirectly through QAbstractButton and QWidget) of QObject, which is the type of the objects in the list ui->myWidget->children(), so I feel like they should be able to cast this way. I haven't worked much with this kind of thing before so I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: So, I can't get the casting to work this way or with the qobject_cast. I HAVE however discovered that I can go from QObject to QWidget, and I think I should be able to go from QWidget to the needed objects with dynamic_cast, but that doesn't work either. Right now I have this:

```
QStringList textlist;
for(int i = 0; i < ui->myWidget->children().size(); i++)
{
    QWidget *qw = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(ui->myWidget->children().at(i)
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        QComboBox *q = dynamic_cast<QComboBox*>(qw);
        if(q)
        {
            textlist.append(q->text());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QCheckBox *q = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(qw);
        if(q)
        {
            textlist.append(q->currentText());
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate the help. Thank you.

UPDATE2: I haven't found much online that helps with this still, so I may as well ask as well, if there is anyway to do this WITHOUT casting, i.e. getting the objects directly from the QWidget in their original type, I would really appreciate that as well. I'm not heartset on my current strategy or anything, it was just the only way I could think to do it - I'll take anything that works at this point.

Comment: Use `qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ptr)` rather than the C-style casts you're using, and check that the cast succeeds before accessing the text. The way you're using C-style casts is really dangerous, because there's no warning if the cast fails. With a failed C-style cast, at best you get a crash when you go to try and use the pointer. At worst, you get silent data corruption.

Comment: @Slavik81 Is there any trick to getting that to work? It's giving me errors like "cannont convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'QCheckBox*'"

Comment: @Slavik81 Never mind about my comment there, it was just a dumb typo on my part. Thanks!

Comment: In general, avoid C style cast in C++ code, and never use it with OOP objects. Note that pointers to *same* object instance can have different value depending on type of the *pointer*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should think about using [`qobject_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast). After the cast you should also check if the object is valid.

```
QStringList textlist;
for(int i = 0; i < ui->myWidget->children().size(); i++)
{
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        QCheckBox *q = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(ui->myWidget->children().at(i));
        if(q)
           textlist.append(q->text());
    }
    else
    {
        QComboBox *q = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ui->myWidget->children().at(i));
        if(q)
           textlist.append(q->currentText());
    }
}
```

But this still seems like a bad design to me. The widget class that contains the comboboxes and checkboxes should have a function, that goes through the checkboxes and comboboxes and returns a `QStringList`. Then you could just call that function.

Here is an example

mywidget.h:

```
namespace Ui {
class MyWidget;
}

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWidget();
    QStringList getComboTextList();
    QStringList getCheckBoxTextList();

private:
    Ui::MyWidget *ui;
    QList<QComboBox*> comboList;
    QList<QCheckBox*> checkList;
};
```

mywidget.cpp:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox(this);
        this->layout()->addWidget(checkBox);
        checkBox->setText(QString("Check box #%1").arg(i));
        checkList.append(checkBox);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
        this->layout()->addWidget(comboBox);
        comboBox->addItem("Combo box item 1");
        comboBox->addItem("Combo box item 2");
        comboList.append(comboBox);
    }
}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}

QStringList MyWidget::getComboTextList()
{
    QStringList returnList;
    for(int i = 0; i < comboList.length(); i++)
    {
        returnList << comboList[i]->currentText();
    }
    return returnList;
}

QStringList MyWidget::getCheckBoxTextList()
{
    QStringList returnList;
    for(int i = 0; i < checkList.length(); i++)
    {
        returnList << checkList[i]->text();
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Then in your other class you can just call `getCheckBoxTextList` or `getComboTextList` like this:

```
QStringList comboTextList = myWidget->getComboBoxList();
QStringList checkTextList = myWidget->getCheckBoxTextList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same thing too, but I couldn't find any functions like that in QWidget. Also, like I asked Slavik above, is there a trick to getting qobject_cast to work without errors?

Comment: Actually, unfortunately I need to retract the last comment. I was running some more tests and the if statements prevented it from crashing, but the casts still don't seem to work, when I put an else in with the if(q), it goes to the else statements :( For the record, I have it in the format of the answer above, just with else statements added to go along with the if(q) statements 

EDIT: I DID, however, discover that it can successfully cast from QObject* to QWidget*, so if I can figure out how to go from QWidget* to QCheckBox* I'll be set.

Comment: @thnkwthprtls The reason your cast fails is because you are trying to cast some object to `QCheckBox` even though it's completely different type. This is because your logic doesn't work. Casting it to `QWidget` frist won't help you. You can remove your `if(i %2 == 0)` statement and the corresponding `else` statement and just check if the cast works. But I still would recommend that you subclass `QWidget`, add your `QCheckBox` and `QComboBox` objects there, and add a function that goes through them and returns a `QStringList`. That way you won't have to do any casting, and it will be more OOP.

Comment: But aren't QCheckBox and QComboBox already subclasses of QWidget?

Comment: ...OK, so I honestly have no idea at all why, but yesterday afternoon when I tried this it didn't work... and now this morning it does haha. I didn't change anything in the code, maybe it was something wrong with the compiled object files or something... honestly I don't know, but now your code works, thanks!